# Close old OTR hood vent hole on exterior stucco wall

Tags: exhaust-vent, stucco, hole-repair

How do I permanently close and seal the old vent hole on the outside stucco wall ?

Do I have to remove the old metal  vent (*see photo*) or can I just put stucco patch on top of the metal and fill in the entire hole with stucco patch ?

What is the correct way to fill hole on stucco wall ?.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need more than patch or filler for that large of an area. Chicken wire, construction cloth or even expanded metal can be used to make it a quality repair. At that point you could patch , there is enough wire showing just make sure to overlap and work the base coat in so it is held in place by the wire.

Comment: "*At that point you could patch*" Should we assume you mean to say: YES  you should use **stucco patch**? That is  part of    the OP's question.

Comment: @alaska man I can’t say yes to a patch without knowing the type some are only topcoat, some are multi purpose with addmix to make water resistant. however it is done it will probably fail unless wire or mesh is added I have seen top coat used with wire that held up for several years after the house was sold but the wire held it in place. It had so many cracks it looked like tempered glass.

Comment: @EdBeal Should I bother removing the old duct which is pushed in (as see in the pic) or just repair on top of it ?

Comment: The duct provides a “backing” I might put a piece of builders felt on it to decouple the stucco but I usually have a part of a roll. Something there could be a good idea if there is a chance the metal inside will get removed later. But I would probably leave it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the old duct is pushed back to the level of the stucco, so there's nothing interfering with your patch.

Comment: While this is an astute observation, it does **NOT** answer the question: "*What is the correct way to fill hole on stucco wall ?*"